# Advanced custom fields, php variables and displaying content

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, advanced-custom-fields

I have an advanced custom field group, and inside the group and inside the group are a few fields and one select field in where the user selects a category.  I want to output onto the page based on what category has been chosen.

Here is the code I was trying:

```
  <?php 

    $limit = get_option('posts_per_page');
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    query_posts('post_type=Specialist_post&showposts=' . $limit . '&paged=' . $paged);
    $wp_query->is_archive = true; $wp_query->is_home = false;

    if(have_posts()) : 
    while(have_posts()) : 
    the_post(); 




    if(get_field('category') == "1402")
    { ?>

       <div class="row wheelsspecial">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

    <h3><?php the_field('company_name'); ?></h3>
    <p><?php the_field('brief_description'); ?></p>
    <p><?php the_field('contact_number'); ?></p>
    <a href=""><?php the_field('website_address'); ?></a><br />
    <a href="mailto:"><?php the_field('email'); ?></a>


   <?php } else if (get_field('category') == "1403") {?>


    <div class="row tuningspecial">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

    <h3><?php the_field('company_name'); ?></h3>
    <p><?php the_field('brief_description'); ?></p>
    <p><?php the_field('contact_number'); ?></p>
    <a href=""><?php the_field('website_address'); ?></a><br />
    <a href="mailto:"><?php the_field('email'); ?></a>





   <?php } ?>



<?php
  endwhile;
  else: 
  ?>


  Oops, there are no posts.

  <?php
  endif;
  ?>
```

This now outputs nothing, if i echo the field category its returning 1403, so i would think it at least outputs the else if, maybe this whole code design is wrong. Essentially i want to print different into different divs based on the category selected.

Comment: You're not using `echo` on any of `the_feild()` methods. Is this intentional?

Comment: Also, is `the_field()` equivalent to `get_field()`? You could use `echo get_field('company_name');` as this seems to be returning OK.

Comment: I suppose not but the_field() works without echo

Comment: the_field ouputs, get_field is different it gets it

Answer (score 0):

Did it this way, not the ideal solution, works for now, just needs a code review

```
    <div class="row wheelsspecial">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <?php 

      $args = array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'Specialist_post',
        'meta_key' => 'category',
        'meta_value' => '1402'
      );

      $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

       if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>

        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

              <h3><?php the_field('company_name'); ?></h3>
              <p><?php the_field('brief_description'); ?></p>
              <p><?php the_field('contact_number'); ?></p>
              <a href=""><?php the_field('website_address'); ?></a><br />
              <a href="mailto:"><?php the_field('email'); ?></a>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php wp_reset_query();  ?>

</div>
</div>

  <div class="row tuningspecial">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <?php 

      $args = array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'Specialist_post',
        'meta_key' => 'category',
        'meta_value' => '1403'
      );

      $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

       if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>

        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

              <h3><?php the_field('company_name'); ?></h3>
              <p><?php the_field('brief_description'); ?></p>
              <p><?php the_field('contact_number'); ?></p>
              <a href=""><?php the_field('website_address'); ?></a><br />
              <a href="mailto:"><?php the_field('email'); ?></a>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php wp_reset_query();  ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks all